# Bootstrap toggle button not functioning

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've been having trouble getting my bootstrap toggle button to display menu items 'What We Do', 'About', or 'Contact' when clicked. It collapses properly but will not work when clicked.

I've played around with as many things as I know how to fix it, but cannot figure it out.

```
    <!--Logo-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ACS</a>
    </div>

    <!--Menu Items-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap-4?

Comment: No, I apologize. I believe that I am using 3.3.7, as I could not get v4 to work, either. I'm new to this and am not sure if I have even posted my question in the proper place.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? For example, we cannot see from this if your elements are wrapped in `navbar navbar-default` (required for the hamburger icon to display).  We also can't see if there is perhaps an issue with your not including the CSS or JavaScript correctly.

Comment: Apologies. Here is the upper part of the code/link to CSS:                                 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>ADVISORS Consulting Services</title>
</head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web_build.css">
<body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is not correctly linked to the button in your code. What is appearing as ACS is the link, however this link is not targeted at the menu, the button is.

I have included a snippet. You only need some minor changes to make it work.

(btw, I only noticed now, it uses bootstrap 3.36 - I created the snippet using jsbin originally using 'Bootstrap latest' library!)

```css
.navbar-header button {
  color: #337ab7;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">ACS
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
  </div>

  <!--Menu Items-->
  <div id="mainNavBar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always ensure that, when adding your script files or cdn, you put the jquery.js file or cdn link before the bootstrap.js file or cdn link.

You can read more on it on the official website of bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/